# How to set timezone in quarkus to UTC

Tags: quarkus

I am using quarkus 1.2.0.

**General:**

The client browser is asking for data from the server. Server (Quarkus app) is receiving the time in utc from the client. (ok) Now the server should compare the data from the database with the clients browser-time and should return every data from the database, which is after the clients-time.

I have postgres as database. Every time when I save new data or modifie data into the database I save the data with the UTC time.
I enforce this with `<property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" value="UTC"/>` in the persistence.xml.
I have checked this, the data is save in utc time in the postgres database.

**The problem:**

Although the data is save in utc in the database, when quarkus fetches the data from the database, it transfers the data to the local timezone (GMT +0100).
Now I have the problem that the server is comparing the data converted to (GMT) with the clients time (UTC).

How can I force quarkus to use UTC timezone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to pass `-Duser.timezone=UTC` when executing your jar?

A Quarkus app is just a standard Java app.

Another option would be to set it up in your application directly by creating a CDI bean observing the startup event:

```java
@Singleton
public class TimezoneSettings {

    public void setTimezone(@Observes StartupEvent startupEvent) {
        System.setProperty("user.timezone", "UTC");
    }
}
```

I'm just not entirely sure it will be early enough for your application though. You will have to try it.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this. Several problems with this approach:
1. This is working when i run the jar directly. When I program and test my application in quarkus dev mode this isn`t working. Quarkus dev mode is ignoring this property (seems for me like a bug)
2. I want to set UTC anyhow in the program. Because every client requests are coming in utc, therefore I want to force UTC on the server, without any user interaction

Comment: I added another option to my answer.

Comment: The programmatic approach through the startup event does not work (anymore?). Any other solution?

Comment: Could you create a GitHub issue with a reproducer of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Not Sure if dev mode issue has been resolved, you can set this in your application class too ` System.setProperty("user.timezone", "UTC");`

Answer (score 3):

If using hibernate:    https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.jdbc.timezone=UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works in quarkus dev mode as well:

```java
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.TimeZone;


public class YourApplication extends Application {

    public YourApplication() {
        super();
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }
}
```